# How to fix IndexOutOfBoundException in Java 8 Streams?

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I was trying to update an outside map in IntStream parallel loop. But it is giving IndexOutOfBoundException before it reaches the end of loop.

```
IntStream.range(0, 16384).parallel().forEach(index -> {
String slotKey = String.valueOf(index);
slotMap.put(slotKey, cacheService.getCountOfKeysInSlots(index));
System.out.println(index);
}
);
```

It gives error when value of i is 16264, which is well before the final value of I (16384)

Appreciate if somebody help me fix the problem.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can reproduce your issue?

Comment: If slotMap isn't thread-safe, anything can happen, since you're using a parallel stream. There is a toMap collector that is designed to do that in a thread-safe way. That won't help if cacheService isn't thread-safe, though. But we have no idea if that's the problem, since the problem is not reproducible, and you haven't posted any stack trace.

Comment: It would help if the OP would run the code without the `.parallel()`, to test the idea by @JBNizet. That is a likely explanation.